# How to read value of custom options from protobuf.js generated code?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf.js

Similar to the example at: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#extensions

Suppose I have a proto like:

```
import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";

extend google.protobuf.FieldOptions {
   string search_key = 7000;
}

message Person {
  string name = 1 [(search_key) = "searchIndex.firstName"];
}
```

then I use the protobufjs-cli to generate a static module:

```
pbjs -t static-module -w commonjs -o compiled.js test.proto
```

How can I then read the descriptor in javascript using the generated module?

Comment: Descriptors are only available with the reflection features, however as mentioned [here](https://github.com/protobufjs/protobuf.js/blob/master/cli/README.md), static-module is `Static code without reflection as a module`. So this is not possible. You would need to use `proto3` or `proto2`.

Comment: Thanks, any chance you could add an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, this required access to either the original .proto file or the output of:

`pbjs -t proto3 -o compiled.proto myfile.proto`

but once I had that it was simply a matter of:

```
import * as protobuf from 'protobufjs';

const root = protobuf.loadSync('test.proto')
const Person = root.lookupType('main.Person')
console.log(Person.fields.name.options!['(search_key)'])
// logs: searchIndex.firstName
```